# Get Facebook page reviews with Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

A try to get reviews from my Facebook Page.
I did this steps:

- created a facebook app
- generate Page Access token with Graph API explorer with this permissions (`pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement, pages_read_user_content`)

When I try to check this request with Graph API Explorer:
`{page-id}/ratings?access_token={page-access-token}`

I get this error message:

```
"error": {
    "message": "(#210) A page access token is required to request this resource.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 210,
    "fbtrace_id": "AzmTNkAFJhlG7EW8j6NcC-X"
}
```

The Facebook app doesn't have reviewed. It can be problem?
Or the request syntax is bad?

Best regards,
Feco

Comment: The error message is likely correct, you are probably using a User Access Token or an App Token instead of a Page Access Token. You can use the access token debugger to see the metadata for your token https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Answer (score 0):

My fault..
I generated user access token.
The debug tool is very helpful to check your type of token.

Comment: Debug Tool -> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/